# Views link image to field

Tags: 7, views, entities

I've created a view with two fields(field_img & field_pdf) and the Format as Fields.

Now I want to download the field_pdf file when I click on the field_img.

How to achieve this one?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use "Rewrite the output of this field" to wrap the image in a link using the "replacement pattern" token for the PDF file url as the href there.

Note you can "Exclude field from display" to add a field to the token list without displaying it.

You'll also need to drag the field, in the field order, above the one you want to use it in as a token for it to be available.

hth